# Terminating idle mysql connections

Tags: mysql, timeout, kill, wait, python-idle

I see a lot of connections are open and remain idle for a long time, say 5 minutes.

Is there any solution to terminate / close it from server without restarting the mysql service?

I am maintaining a legacy PHP system and can not close the connections those are established to execute the query.

Should I reduce the timeout values in my.cnf file those defaults to 8 hours?

```
# default 28800 seconds

interactive_timeout=60
wait_timeout=60
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

#### Manual cleanup:

You can KILL the processid.

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+---------+------------+-------------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id      | User       | Host              | db   | Command | Time  | State | Info                  |
+---------+------------+-------------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-----------------------+
| 1193777 | TestUser12 | 192.168.1.11:3775 | www  | Sleep   | 25946 |       | NULL                  |
+---------+------------+-------------------+------+---------+-------+-------+-----------------------+

mysql> kill 1193777;
```

But:

- the php application might report
  errors (or the webserver, check the
  error logs)
- **don't fix what is not broken** - if you're not short on connections, just
  leave them be.

#### Automatic cleaner service ;)

Or you configure your mysql-server by setting a shorter timeout on [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)

```
mysql> show variables like "%timeout%";
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout          | 5     |
| delayed_insert_timeout   | 300   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50    |
| interactive_timeout      | 28800 |
| net_read_timeout         | 30    |
| net_write_timeout        | 60    |
| slave_net_timeout        | 3600  |
| table_lock_wait_timeout  | 50    |
| wait_timeout             | 28800 |
+--------------------------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Set with:

```
set global wait_timeout=3;
set global interactive_timeout=3;
```

(and also set in your configuration file, for when your server restarts)

But you're treating the symptoms instead of the underlying cause - why are the connections open? If the PHP script finished, shouldn't they close? Make sure your webserver is not using connection pooling...

Comment: can I use this command on a shared host such as hostgator?  I want to reduce the chance of maxing out my mysql connections and getting a TOS email/shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any problem, unless you are not managing them using a connection pool.

If you use connection pool, these connections are re-used instead of initiating new connections. so basically, leaving open connections and re-use them it is less problematic than re-creating them each time.

Comment: can you please suggest how can one reuse the existing open/idle connections instead of creating new one. I am using spring boot 2.1.4 + Hikari cp + mariadb 10.3. Is there any way to configure the reuse property for database connection.