# CommunicationsException when using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have configured a `Hibernate DAO` in my application. Once a client ping that service, my server will use this `DAO` to connect to the database and retrieve some data.

This works fine for a couple of hours (or maybe one day), and then some thing goes wrong. I got exception like this:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   The last packet successfully received from the server was 48,761,817
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   48,761,899 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.

Once I redeploy my service, everything back to normal again. My codes is like this:

public class DeploymentInfoDAO {

```
private static SessionFactory factory = null;

private DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = null;

private CheckLockStatusService checkLockStatusService = new CheckLockStatusService();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public DeploymentInfoDAO() {

}

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param deploymentInfo
 */
public DeploymentInfoDAO(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) {
    this.deploymentInfo = deploymentInfo;
    // this.checkLockStatusService = new CheckLockStatusService();
}

/**
 * SELECT * FROM servicedashboard and converts the results into a list of
 * ServiceRow
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<ServiceRow> getServiceRows() {
    List<ServiceRow> serviceRows = new ArrayList<ServiceRow>();
    if (factory == null){
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }


    // mysql select test
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<DeploymentInfo> deploymentInfos = session
                .createQuery(
                        "FROM com.test.hibernate.pojo.DeploymentInfo")
                .list();

        for (Iterator<DeploymentInfo> iterator = deploymentInfos.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = iterator.next();

            ServiceRow serviceRow = this
                    .convertToServiceRow(deploymentInfo);
            serviceRows.add(serviceRow);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {

        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return serviceRows;

}
}
```

Basically, every client call will create an `DeploymentInfoDAO`, and it will keep using the same `static`  `SessionFactory` once it is created until it is not `null`.

It seems that after several hours, this `SessionFactory` became invalid but still not null.

What's the best practice to modify the code? And also, in the exception, it suggest `using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true'` to avoid this problem, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your server terminates the connection with MySQL after 8 hours of inactivity (8 hours is default)
you can use `autoReconnect=true` in jdbc url

### Syntax

```
jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db>?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: I searched a while online and some one said: `using autoReconnect has a side effect about data consistency`. I am not sure whether this is the best practice.

Comment: the sideeffect occurs when application is not handling SQLException. when a connection is stale and you fire a query having autoReconnect will throw exception. You should catch that exception and can retry the query. Alternatively you can increase the wait_timeout at your MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the wait timeout in your server or enable the auto reconnect in your JDBC URL.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I had the same problem. This is because MySQL close connection after a time of inactivity, it is not problem of your application.

One solution is create a dummy query (`SELECT 1`) and execute it every hour (or time that you estimate). This avoid MySQL closes connection.

Another it is increase the time limit of MySQL (This solution I don't like it, many times cannot modify database configuration for some reasons).

More information:

[Terminating idle mysql connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284194/terminating-idle-mysql-connections)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

I hope this help you.

Comment: Well... the first one is really like a work around ... not the best practice to avoid such issue.