# aws rds connects, what are they and how can I reduce the number of connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

on my aws maria db rds instance I got lots of connections ... and then the database is not accassible again.

[image]

in this case there are only 77 connections. but often there are more then 150...

I run a microservice construct with 4 microservices each of them is a playframework application written in scala.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed connections, to double check this login to the RDS instance and run this:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

What could be happening is that your applications are not closing the connection after using it.

Check also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284212/1135424 could help to set better values to the `timeout` variables:

```
set global wait_timeout=3;
set global interactive_timeout=3;
```

Comment: thought about it as well. DB connection is set up with slick. Changed the deprecated version this morning. gonna try if the new profile driver will fix it. thanks