# Close ideal connection of mysql in node js using express js framework

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Below is the create connection code of my application and I am using it in the entire application

```
   const mysql = require('mysql');

const mysql_pool = mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit: 300,
            // connectTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
            // acquireTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
            // timeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
            host: 'host',
            user: 'user',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'database',
            charset: 'utf8mb4'

        });
        module.exports = mysql_pool;
```

Using MySQL connection in other files of the application by requiring the Database connection file

```
const mysqlpool = require('database.js');

   mysqlpool.query('SELECT * from table_name where status="1"', (error, result) => {
        if (!isEmpty(result) && isEmpty(error)) {
            cb({result});

            return false;
        }
```

For such the above function, I have multiple functions in the application when the connection is the ideal state I want to close it instead of automatic release or any other config parameter by using which I can close the connection within 5 seconds if it is the ideal state.

For refernce I am using this module :[Link of mysql module which I am using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: You can do it on DB side. Look this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284194/terminating-idle-mysql-connections

Comment: But I do not want change config of Database ... is any way to handle it on coding side????